# Deserialize JSON to type containing reference to another deserialized object

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit

I have two json arrays with different contained objects and i need to get serialized one array of objects that contains object from second array.

For example i have json response.

```
{
    "shops":[{"id":"id"}],
    "notifications":[{"shop_id":"id"}]
}
```

In result i need to have a list of Notification that will contain references to objects in the shops list. And i want make this in parse/deserialization step